# Need help identifying cause of "type clash on default action"

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I've been working a school assignment and am having difficulty figuring out which issue is causing the multiple warnings below "type clash on default action."  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Warnings received:

```
parser.y:62.9-23: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:71.9-16: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:82.5-23: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <iden>
parser.y:83.5-27: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <iden>
parser.y:104.5-55: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:105.5-60: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:108.5-37: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:122.49-53: warning: type clash on default action: <oper> != <>
parser.y:122.57-60: warning: type clash on default action: <oper> != <>
parser.y:127.5-14: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <iden>
parser.y:157.9-35: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <iden>
parser.y:160.9-20: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <>
parser.y:161.9-21: warning: type clash on default action: <value> != <oper>
```

parser.y

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#include "values.h"
#include "listing.h"
#include "symbols.h"

int yylex();
void yyerror(const char* message);

Symbols<int> symbols;

int result;

%}

%error-verbose

%union
{
    CharPtr iden;
    Operators oper;
    int value;
}

%token <value> INT_LITERAL REAL_LITERAL INTEGER REAL 
%token <iden> IDENTIFIER
%token ARROW 
%token ANDOP OROP 

%token <oper> NOTOP EXPOP MULOP REMOP ADDOP RELOP

%token BOOL_LITERAL BOOLEAN 
%token IF THEN ELSE ENDIF CASE OTHERS ENDCASE WHEN 
%token BEGIN_ END ENDREDUCE FUNCTION  IS REDUCE RETURNS

%type <value>  function_header_ body  variable_ parameter cases case statements statement_ statement reductions exponent expression logical relation term
    factor power primary

%type <oper> operator

%%


function:   
    function_header_ variables body {result = $3;} ;


function_header:    
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER parameters RETURNS type ';' ;

function_header_:
    function_header |
    error ';' {$$ = 0;} ;


statement_:
    statement ';' |
    error ';' {$$ = 0;} ;

variable_:
    variable |
    error ';' {$$ = 0;} ;

variable:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type IS statement_ {symbols.insert($1, $5);} ;

variables:
    variables variable_ |
    ;

parameter: 
    IDENTIFIER ':' type |
    IDENTIFIER ':' type ',' ;

parameters:
    parameters parameter |
    ;

type:
    INTEGER | REAL |
    BOOLEAN ;

body:
    BEGIN_ statement_ END ';' {$$ = $2;} ;

statements:
    statements statement_ |
    statement_ ;


statement:
    expression |
    REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} |
    IF expression THEN statements ELSE statements ENDIF  | 
    CASE expression IS cases OTHERS ARROW statement_ ENDCASE ; 

case:
    WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_;

cases:
    cases case |
    case 
    ;


reductions:
    reductions statement_ {$$ = evaluateReduction($<oper>0, $1, $2);} |
    {$$ = $<oper>0 == ADD ? 0 : 1;} ;

operator:
    NOTOP | MULOP | REMOP | ADDOP | RELOP | ANDOP | OROP ; 

exponent:
    INT_LITERAL |
    REAL_LITERAL |
    IDENTIFIER ;

expression:
    expression OROP logical {$$ = $1 || $3;} |
    logical ;

logical:
    logical ANDOP relation {$$ = $1 && $3;} |
    relation ;

relation:
    relation RELOP term {$$ = evaluateRelational($1, $2, $3);} |
    term ;

term:
    term ADDOP factor {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} |
    factor ;

factor:
    factor MULOP power {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} |
    factor REMOP power {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} |
    power ;

/* right-associative */
power:
  primary EXPOP exponent {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} 
  ;

primary:
    IDENTIFIER {if (!symbols.find($1, $$)) appendError(UNDECLARED, $1);} |
    IDENTIFIER '('expression')' |
    INT_LITERAL |
    REAL_LITERAL |
    BOOL_LITERAL |
    NOTOP primary |
    '(' expression ')' {$$ = $2;}
    ;
%%

void yyerror(const char* message)
{
    appendError(SYNTAX, message);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    firstLine();
    yyparse();
    if (lastLine() == 0)
        cout << "Result = " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

scanner.l

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "values.h"
#include "listing.h"
#include "tokens.h"

int l=0,r=0,cbl=0,cbr=0;

%}

%option noyywrap

ws      [ \t\r]+
comment         \-\-.*\n|\/\/.*\n
line            [\n]
arrow            =>

if               if|IF 
endcase          endcase|ENDCASE 
case             case|CASE 
endif            endif|ENDIF 
else             else|ELSE 
others           others|OTHERS 
real             real|REAL 
then             then|THEN 
when             when|WHEN 
begin            begin|BEGIN 
boolean          boolean|BOOLEAN 
endreduce        endreduce|ENDREDUCE 
end              end|END 
function         function|FUNCTION 
integer          integer|INTEGER 
is               is|IS 
reduce           reduce|REDUCE 
returns          returns|RETURNS 
and              and|AND    
or               or|OR 
not              not|NOT 
bool_lit         true|false|TRUE|FALSE
bad_underscore  [A-Za-z0-9_]*[_]{2}[A-Za-z0-9_]*|^[_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|[A-Za-z0-9_]*[_]+$
digit           [0-9]
int             [\-|\+]{0,1}{digit}+
punc            [\(\),:;]
real_lit        [\-|\+]{0,1}[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+[e|E][\-|\+][0-9]+|[\-|\+]{0,1}[0-9]*[\.][0-9]+|[\-|\+]{0,1}[0-9]+[\.][0-9]*

id              [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]* 
%%

{ws}        { ECHO; }
{comment}   { ECHO; nextLine();}
{line}      { ECHO; nextLine();}
{arrow}        { ECHO; return(ARROW); }


"<"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = LESS; return(RELOP); }
">"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = GREATER; return(RELOP); }
">="    { ECHO; yylval.oper = GREATER_OR_EQUALS; return(RELOP); }
"<="    { ECHO; yylval.oper = LESS_OR_EQUALS; return(RELOP); }
"="     { ECHO; yylval.oper = EQUALS; return(RELOP); }
"+"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = ADD; return(ADDOP); }
"-"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = SUBTRACT; return(ADDOP); }
"**"    { ECHO; yylval.oper = EXPONENT; return(EXPOP); }
"*"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = MULTIPLY; return(MULOP); }
"/"     { ECHO; yylval.oper = DIVIDE; return(MULOP); }
"REM"   { ECHO; yylval.oper = REMAINDER; return(REMOP); }
"rem"   { ECHO; yylval.oper = REMAINDER; return(REMOP); }


{if}            { ECHO; return(IF); }
{endcase}       { ECHO; return(ENDCASE); }
{case}          { ECHO; return(CASE); }
{endif}         { ECHO; return(ENDIF); }
{else}          { ECHO; return(ELSE); }
{others}        { ECHO; return(OTHERS); }
{real}          { ECHO; return(REAL); }
{then}          { ECHO; return(THEN); }
{when}          { ECHO; return(WHEN); }
{begin}         { ECHO; return(BEGIN_); }
{boolean}       { ECHO; return(BOOLEAN); }
{endreduce}     { ECHO; return(ENDREDUCE); }
{end}           { ECHO; return(END); }
{function}      { ECHO; return(FUNCTION); }
{integer}       { ECHO; return(INTEGER); }
{is}            { ECHO; return(IS); }
{reduce}        { ECHO; return(REDUCE); }
{returns}       { ECHO; return(RETURNS); }
{and}           { ECHO; return(ANDOP); }
{or}            { ECHO; return(OROP); }
{not}           { ECHO; return(NOTOP); }
{real_lit}  { ECHO; return(REAL_LITERAL); }
{bool_lit}  { ECHO; return(BOOL_LITERAL); }


{id}        { ECHO; yylval.iden = (CharPtr)malloc(yyleng + 1); 
            strcpy(yylval.iden, yytext); return(IDENTIFIER);}
{int}       { ECHO; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return(INT_LITERAL); }
{punc}      { ECHO; return(yytext[0]); }
.       { ECHO; appendError(LEXICAL, yytext); }

%%
```

Answer (score 1):

These are type mismatches on the default action from a rule that has no explicit action.  The first one is coming from the rule

```
function_header_: function_header
```

on line 62.  Since there's no action here, it gets the action `{ $$ = $1; }`, but `$$` has type `<value>` (from the `%type <value> function_header_` declaration), while `$1` has no type (so `<>`, as there's no `%type` declaration for `function_header`)